# What is system_runtime_cpu_usage metric in Prometheus?

Tags: .net-core, prometheus, prometheus-net

I am using .net core application with the Prometheus client.
In the metrics endpoint, I can see some metrics are exported but I want to know the implementation of those matrices. But in the client git repo, I could not find any implementation for these matrices.
Here is the version I am using:
prometheus-net" Version="8.0.0
prometheus-net.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0"

Exported Metrics:

- system_runtime_threadpool_queue_length
- system_runtime_cpu_usage

Where are those metrics actually implemented?

Comment: Have you tried googling the names? These match the names of the .NET performance counters pretty closely. They aren't provided by Prometheus. If you search for `prometheus system_runtime_threadpool_queue_length` for example you'll find in the top results the [Collect Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/metrics-collection) page in the .NET documentation and [Well-Known Event Counters in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters). On Windows .NET performance counters are visible in Performance Monitor

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw that .NET documentation but I did not realize that is related to or same metrics. I thought those are coming from the Prometheus client and was looking at how those values are set.